# JSON IE7 jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JS code:

```
  var data = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
  $('#name').live("change", function() {
    name = data[$(this).val()];
    alert(name);
  });
```

It works fine in FireFox, but in IE7 I get the follow JS error:

```
 Object doesn't support this property or method.
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, use `.on()`

Comment: Who is `obj[$(this).val()]` ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes Sorry my bad, it should be data[$(this).val()];

Comment: on which line you get the error ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you declareted the name?

var name = ob...

The IE needs to declarate js variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplate.

```
      var data = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');  
     $('#name').live("change", function() {
         name = obj[$(this).val()];
         alert(name);   });
```

what is obj?

where you got the error (means which line)

I think any object is returning null values or the functions of js, are not defined

Comment: I'm sorry it was a typo, it should be data[$(this).val()];